# "Inverse" Limit?

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination, limit

I'm using MySQL to store financial stuff, and using the data to build, among other things, registers of all the transactions for each account.  For performance reasons - and to keep the user from being overwhelmed by a gargantuan table - I paginate the results.

Now, as part of the register, I display a running balance for the account.  So if I'm displaying 20 transactions per page, and I'm displaying the second page, I use the data as follows:

- **Transactions 0 - 19:** Ignore them - they're more recent than the page being looked at.
- **Transactions 20 - 39:** Select everything from these - they'll be displayed.
- **Transactions 40 - ??:** Sum the amounts from these so the running balance is accurate.

It's that last one that's annoying me.  It's easy to select the *first* 40 transactions using a LIMIT clause, but is there something comparable for everything *but* the first 40?  Something like "LIMIT -40"?

I know I can do this with a COUNT and a little math, but the actual query is a bit ugly (multiple JOINs and GROUP BYs), so I'd rather issue it as few times as possible.  And this seems useful enough to be included in SQL - and I just don't know about it.  Does anybody else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) says:

> The `LIMIT` clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the `SELECT` statement. `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these
>   exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified
>     using ? placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using
>     integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL
>     5.5.6.
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
> ```
>
> **To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result
>   set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This
>   statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:**
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
> ```

Next time, please use the documentation as your first port of call.

Comment: Makes sense, even if it is a bit of a hack.  I'm taking this over Adrian's as it looks more likely to use indices.  So, despite the fact that you removed the part of my original question where I was civil and thanked people for helping me:  Thank you.

Comment: @Xavier: I removed only the redundant and unnecessary tags and signature. Please stop writing them in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can hack it this way:

```
select sel.*
from
(
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.*
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, YourTableOrYourSubSelect t
) sel
where rownum > 40
```

It's kinda like having Oracle's rownum in MySQL.