# MYSQL start at nth result (opposite of LIMIT)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-limit

Is there a SQL command for starting at a certain amount of results?
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=1 BEGIN AT 100
```

Comment: Limit is the oposite of what i want. i want to skip the first 100 results.

Comment: Im reading some documentation, you might be right. Limit looks like it supports range values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558256/inverse-limit

Comment: cant you use like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=1 limit 100,100;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=1 LIMIT 100,500;

result will show 500 value from 100

Comment: This wont show all records from 100, only the section 100 to 500

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a temporary **Row Number** then use that as criteria for your starting point which is in your case 100, like:

```
 SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT (@RowNum := @RowNum + 1) as Row, tbl.* FROM tbl, 
        (SELECT @RowNum:=0) ctr
       ) t
 WHERE Row >= 100
```

See <kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db940b/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
```

In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=1 BEGIN AT 99,18446744073709551615
```

---

More information:

For prepared statements, you can use placeholders (supported as of MySQL version 5.0.7). The following statements will return one row from the tbl table:

```
SET @a=1;
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @a;
```

The following statements will return the second to sixth row from the tbl table:

```
SET @skip=1; SET @numrows=5;
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT ?, ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @skip, @numrows;
```

Comment: I didn't see them meanwhile I was looking for. Be aware that the answer you accept is limited.